# Create multiple compressed folders in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, zip, 7-zip

I need using 7zip for create multiple compressed folders in Linux. Same case as here (But this guide is only for Windows): https://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Multiple-Compressed-Folders-in-One-Go

7zz: https://hastebin.com/ahitasivad.sql

Does anyone know a command that creates a 7zip archive from each folder separately?.

Thanks.

Comment: Answered at [compression - Create separate 7z archives for each directory in the current directory and additionally parallelize through GNU Parallel - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456954/create-separate-7z-archives-for-each-directory-in-the-current-directory-and-addi)

Comment: It does not work

Comment: `ls -d */ 7zz a "/home/zzz/Desktop/rts/{}.7z" {}`